# Change html text using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the text of h2 , when the user clicks a button.

Javascript :

```
$("#GoButton").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").html("Hello World"); 
    });
```

and the html :

```
<a href="#jobResPage" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="GoButton">GO</a>
```

I have tried to switch links so jQuery will load first (that solved another problem).

Still can't find what im doing wrong.

Also tried :

```
$("#GoButton").click(function() {
    $("#myDiv").innerHtml("Hello World"); 
    });
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue exactly?

Comment: please provide code in jsfiddle

Comment: you want to change the text inside the tag?

Comment: You code is correct with `$("#myDiv").html("Hello World");`. Check if you have included jquery library in your html, id should be unique for all elements.

Comment: The text in #myDiv (h2 element) don't get the values i want after the user clicks a button

Comment: Is DOM ready when you select the `a` element?

Comment: where is `myDiv` and where is `h2` in your html?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0oc53fdd/

Comment: how do i check if DOM is ready? and why?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/asdasdasdas/0oc53fdd/1/

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas You haven't loaded jQuery in your fiddle. And jQuery doesn't have `innerHTML` method, use `text` or `html` method instead. For document ready see http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript (binding a function on the click) may be executed too early, like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ug7f0te1/) : http://jsfiddle.net/ug7f0te1/

Try binding events after the DOM is fully loaded:

```
$(function(){
    $("#GoButton").click(function() {
        $("#myDiv").html("Hello World"); 
        });
});
```

Comment: thank u ! that solves the problem ! if i had 15+ rep i would up answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need ensure if DOM is loaded already using `$(function(){.. });` and prevent default behaviour of link using `e.preventDefault()`

```
$(function(){
    $("#GoButton").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myDiv").html("Hello World"); 
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/rc53y51d/3)**

Comment: You need to load jquery library which is available on the left panel drop down http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/0oc53fdd/4/

Comment: add this `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your html page just before script in my answer. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

```
$("#myDiv").html("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to change text than you can make use of text() not of html() method

```
$("#myDiv").text("Hello World");
```

---

Update

this is working you need to do proper setting for this in jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/0oc53fdd/5/

[image]

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas - this is working you need to do proper setting for this in jquery : http://jsfiddle.net/0oc53fdd/5/

Answer (score 0):

here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/utkarshk/h0vmmdn8/

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">fd</div>
<h2 id="mydiv1">4343</h2>
<a href="#jobResPage" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="GoButton">GO</a>
```

JS.

```
$("#GoButton").click(function() {
   $("#mydiv1").html("Hello World"); 
   $("#mydiv").html("Hello World"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be clearer if you post all your HTML. From a guess, here's something which does what I think you want:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="myDiv">
      <h2 id="myHeader">Click Go</h2>
      <p><a href="#jobResPage" data-role="button" data-inline="true" id="GoButton">GO</a></p>
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(window).load(function() {
        $("#GoButton").click(function() {
          $("#myHeader").html("Hello World");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
function here()
{
//alert(document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("myHeader").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv">
<h2 id="myHeader">Header</h2>
<button id="GoButton" onclick="here();">GO</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope you can get something from it.